# Specify an existing LiveData object for the liveData kotlin builder function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

For example, we can **create** a `LiveData` object using a `liveData` builder function:

```kotlin
var liveData: LiveData<String> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    delay(1000)
    emit ("hello")

    delay(1000)
    emit ("world")
}
```

This is useful in `ViewModel`, I create a `LiveData` object that receives multiple data values from an asynchronous heavy function in one line.

But what if I **already have** a `MutableLiveData` object and just want to post values there, without creating a new `LiveData` object? How can I do this?

I need a way to asynchronously emit multiple values into existed `MutableLiveData` object inside a `ViewModel` scope to automatically finish all running tasks when the ViewModel will be cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can post to a MutableLiveData in a coroutine launched from `viewModelScope`.

```
private val myMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun someFun() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        myMutableLiveData.value = “Hello”
        delay(500L)
        myMutableLiveData.value = “World”

        myMutableLiveData.value = someSuspendFunctionRetriever()

        val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            someBlockingCallRetriever()
        }
        myMutableLiveData.value = result

        // or use post() when not on Main dispatcher:
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val result = someBlockingCallRetriever()
            myMutableLiveData.post(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I found a similar approach too. It is also possible to specify a context directly in `launch` builder function: `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {liveData.postValue("")}`

Comment: Many functions in the Android library assume you are calling from the main thread and so it’s convention to usually keep coroutines on the main dispatcher. Blocking functions are relatively rare and so they are usually a fraction of the lines in your coroutine, so they can be wrapped in `withContext`. An exception would be a very short coroutine that doesn’t have to interact with any main-only functions or objects.

Comment: But what exactly is the problem to run coroutines in non-main thread? The more main thread unloaded is better, isn't it?

Comment: It’s by no means a rule, but I think it’s cleaner to keep long coroutines on Main and use `.value =` since so many classes in Android don’t have a `post` variant so you often have to use the main dispatcher anyway somewhere in your coroutine. This also ensures all your ViewModel properties are only touched on the main thread so there won’t be concurrency issues with non-coroutine code also working with the properties. And it makes your coroutines match the lifecycle functions where almost all code is called from the main thread.

Comment: If you’re doing anything you think is CPU intensive enough that you would see a gain by moving it off Main, you can use `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` for that piece of code. I do that when parsing long lists before passing them to a LiveData. But just setting values to properties is trivial and is fine to do on the main thread.

Comment: Could you suggest some articles to read to know better how to use coroutines and dispatchers in Android?

Comment: After reading the official docs, I found that reading these articles by the coroutines design lead helped make the concepts click for me. But these are not Android specific. [One](https://elizarov.medium.com/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761) [Two](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc) There is also an Android CodeLab that teaches some basics of using coroutines: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines#0